# VirtualEnv don't save django installation

Tags: django, pip

I'm learning about Django from "Python Django 7 Hour Course" mady by Traversy Media on YT. I'm doing exactly the same things as he and everything works fine. But, every time I'm deactivating venv, after reentering, I can't use django-admin and pip freeze is not showing any installation of django. Do I need to save it somewhere?
I'm using pip 22.0.3 and django 4.0.3

[screen of pip freeze in env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Q2V.png)

Answer (score 1):

After you open your code in the Visual Studio Code or other editor that you use, you should activate your virtual env in the terminal with `source .venv/bin/activate` (for Linux/Mac) or `.venv/Scripts/activate` where `.venv` is the name of the folder of your virtual env that you created earlier.

After that your activated virtual env should appear in the terminal like this:
[image]

If not, what it looks like for you? Can you provide screenshots?

Comment: Ok, I edited post. 
I was entering venv and both in venv and outside of it there isn't any django instance

Comment: And maybe I'm not naming folders, aplications etc. like in a video, but I pay attention to it. It helps me learning - I need to really undestand the code, not just rewriting it

Comment: And I am deactivating venv before leaving

Comment: Maybe you didn't install Django in virtual env, but instead did it globally. Try to run `pip install django` when virtual env activated.

Comment: Yes, I installed django globally first, but it was like two weeks ago. Long story short - I installed it, get overwhelmed with functionality and cmd, so I switched to learng Git first. Then, two days ago I uninstalled django globally, then installed on virtual env. Now I don't have both globally and locally. So yes, 'pip install django' will work, but I shouldn't install it every time I want to back to project, right?